# ASP.NET 6 MVC with EF - Dropdownlist with condition(IF)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, entity-framework-6

Making an ASP.NET 6 MVC connecting to SQL server through EF where you pick an option using a Dropdownlist from the Incident class when creating a Transaction classobject thus binding them together. However an Incident is often active during a limited time window so they all have a Incident.IsActive boolean(managed in another view and works). The Dropdownlist itself works but I want to limit it to only showing active Incidents if(Incident.IsActive). The real issue is that I dont fully understand the syntax to manipulate the object I get back from the DB through EF.

Transaction controller has this method for Creating a new transaction, here if would like to add something akin to if(Incident.isActive) display it in this SelectList

```
        public TransactionController(MyAppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            //display the dropdownlist, here I assume you would iterate through it and only pick IsActive            
            ViewBag.Incident = new SelectList(_context.Incidents.ToList(), "IncidentId", "IncidentName");
            return View();
        }
```

Assume that the logic should be dealt with in the Transaction controller but this is how it's displayed in the Transaction/Create view.

```
                <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Incident.IncidentId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Incident.IncidentId" asp-items="@ViewBag.Incident" class="form-control">
                    <option>Pick an incident</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Incident.IncidentId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Might not be relevant but here is also the Transaction/Create Post method.

```
        // POST: Transactions/Create       
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] Transaction transaction)
        {
            
            ModelState.Remove("Incident.IncidentName");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                transaction.Incident = _context.Incidents.Find(transaction.Incident.IncidentId);
                _context.Add(transaction);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewBag.Incident = new SelectList(_context.Incidents.ToList(), "IncidentId", "IncidentName");
            return View(transaction);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Dropdownlist itself works but I want to limit it to only showing
> active Incidents if(Incident.IsActive).

The easiest way to show the active Incidents is to add a where clause to filter the data when query the Incidents from the database (using _context). The query statement like this:

```
ViewBag.Incident = new SelectList(_context.Incidents.Where(c => c.isActive == true).ToList(), "IncidentId", "IncidentName");
```

Before adding the `where` clause, the result will contain the active or inactive Incidents:

[image]

After adding the `where` clause, the result only contains the active options:

[Note] Both in the Get and Post methods, you should add the `where` clause in query statement.

[image]

Here are some relates articles about LINQ query operations, you can refer to them:

[Basic LINQ Query Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations)

[where clause (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-clause)

[LINQ Operators And Lambda Expression - Syntax & Examples](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/babu_2082/linq-operators-and-lambda-expression-syntax-examples/)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks for pointing me towards the proper documentation too.